# How do i specify the version of a module(django) on atom?

Tags: python, django, path

I'm trying to run a code I imported from github on my laptop. I think i know where the problem is; as the code is using django v2, and when I do : python -m django --version on my laptop it tells me I'm running on django v1. I installed django v2 but can't "connect it".

I guess my problem is in the path taken, could anyone help?

Comment: How did you install django v2?

Comment: I did pip install django==2.2.1

Comment: Are using windows or Linux os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **first step:** you must install `pip` and `virtualenv` package:

- *install **pip** package on **windows**:* `python -m pip install -U pip` or upgrade with `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`  if not work you must check Windows PATH or Environment variables for add python.
- *install **pip** package on **Linux or mac**:* `pip2 install -U pip` or upgrade with `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` [Help link](https://shellhacks.com/python-install-pip-mac-ubuntu-centos/)

In **second step:** you must install `virtualenv` package:

- *install **virtualenv** package on **windows**:* `pip install virtualenv`
- *install **pip** package on **Linux**:*`sudo pip3 install virtualenv`  [Help link for install pip and virtualenv on linux](https://gist.github.com/Geoyi/d9fab4f609e9f75941946be45000632b)

In **third step:** you must create and activate virtual environment for install project requirements package.

- Create a virtual environment with: `virtualenv env` command.
- Go to "ProjectRoot/env/scripts" direction, and write `activate` and enter.
- Then go back to where folder that exists requirements.txt project file, and enter `pip install -r requirements.txt` for install project requirements. maybe Django version (`django==2.x`) does not exist in requirements.txt so you can add Django version into requirements.txt, and again enter `pip install -r requirements.txt` for install Django and check Django version with `django-admin --version` command.
  Now go to the folder that exists manage.py file and enter below commands:

  python manage.py migrate
  python manage.py makemigrations

and if you want to login as an admin user for additional content to the database you must create a superuser with `python manage.py createsuperuser` and enter the name, email, and password.
Then enter `python manage.py runserver` command.
Congratulations, Now your project is running on 127.0.0.1:8000.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I went in my cmd prompt and it worked. Somehow though I still can't run my env in atom??? I'm running it on the host server on a cmd prompt and it work just fine!

Answer (score 0):

Just get the src folder and than create a new env and add the  src folder in it. There should be a txt file where all the packages are. Run this command inside the env pip install -r  nameOfTheTxtFile.txt. This is going to get all the packages that was used to create the project and install it. This way you will not face any problem with the version.  The txt file looks like this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you can use the following method:

pip install virtualenv
Go to "ProjectRoot/env/scripts" direction, and write `activate` and enter.
go back and run `pip install -r requirements.txt`
then run `python manage.py makemigrations`
and `python manage.py migrate`
if you want to create a user use:

`python manage.py createsuperuser`

and finally, run `python manage.py runserver`
now you have your server working at http://127.0.0.1:8000